# Android keeps putting default icon in phone

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have changed icons, in mipmap folders. In my AndroidManifest:

```
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/launcher"
```

But the icon drawn in the phone is the default (the green with the droid). I have even deleted the ic_launcher.png and ic_launcher_round.png files...

Uninstalled and reinstaled a lot of times. Clean/rebuild also a lot of times. Nothing works.

This has me scratching my head for a while.

Any help?

Comment: What launcher are You using? I was using Google Launcher and by uninstalling & installing I was able to refresh app's launcher icon.

Comment: Default Launcher. As I said, Uninstalled and reinstalled lots of times.

Comment: did you also replace the icons in mipmap-hdpi, -xhdpi, etc?

Comment: Try this way, select project's `app` folder -> right mouse click on it -> New > Image Asset -> select any image - then rebuild app and run. Tell me if app's icons has changed.

Comment: Yes I did. I have checked them a lot of times, and the are the proper icons. They are square, if that it is important.

Comment: @deadfish, by doing what you said is taking the right icon. Why wasn't taking it before? Any explanation? Also, put it in an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Maybe You were using resources from wrong drawable-`zzz` and that file has never been changed before.

Comment: But when I doble-click the icon, the right icon was showing, not the default.

Comment: Okay, are You sure that the file had the same name in all drawable-`zzz` folders? There could be any error in cache. To fix that, You should execute option Invalidate Caches from Android Studio by clicking in menu -> File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart. Some problems can be solved by rebuilding and cleaning project and some by invalidating and restarting Android Studio.

Comment: Next time I will Invalidate cache, didn't remember. Thanks for your helpand your time, deadfish!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to change app's launcher icon is to use Image Asset option implemented in Android Studio. It handles all common phones dimensions.

More info here - https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#access

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue until I checked that I was using an svg drawable which had some errors which were shown on the bottom left of the Asset Studio dialog and later replaced another png drawable then it worked